# How to alter Outlook's handling of replies to conversations?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am using **Microsoft Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.9126.2315) 32-bit** by way of my company **Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus** account.

The default handling of outgoing e-mail messages, regardless of type, is such that a copy is saved to the **Sent Items** folder which is fine in almost all cases.

With respect to conversations, however, an issue arises when the **Sent Items** folder is purged via the **Delete All** action. All my contributions ( replies ) to the conversation are lost, as you would expect.

The desired behavior would be to have my replies to conversations save to the folder where the conversation lives ***instead*** of the **Sent Items** folder, preventing this data loss from occurring.

Is this possible within **Outlook** or **Office 365**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-where-sent-email-messages-are-saved-bd95ef3b-8c04-466a-8576-d1ce0eabeb2c) for the support page that shows the option.

Basically:

> Change where sent email messages are saved when using an Exchange account
>
> Click File > Options > Mail.
>
> Under Save messages, make sure the Save copies of messages in the Sent Items folder check box is selected.
>
> Select the **When replying to a message that is not in the Inbox, save the reply in the same folder** check box.

Comment: I had already made those changes. Interesting. To be fair, most of my testing was from within the **Inbox** and the option specifically states _not in the Inbox_. That works as intended. However, I'm still left with the undesired behavior for conversations in the **Inbox**.

Comment: You can create rules to move them to other folders as they arrive.  I do this to organize in-house departments, clients, etc.  Depending on the size of your org./clientele.  I do this so that anything that remains in the inbox is either garbage, or something new that I need to check on, but is not a priority.

Comment: I do that as well ( or at least I try to ). Every attempt to achieve Inbox Zero, though, usually ends up OBE'd. I appreciate the response.